# How to scrape text from a webpage using it's title tag or a combination of div id + classes?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-scraping, string-parsing

So this might be quite a broad question but I'm still pretty new and wanted some input on how I can achieve this so I can finish my project!

I am working on freecodecamps "Random Quote Machine" that uses an API to pull random quotes using AJAX and JSON. I wanted to try and go above and beyond that by scraping all the quotes from this site: https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/deep.html

I noticed while looking through the console that all the quotes are in separate divs with either titles of "view quote" or "view author" as well as classes with the format "b-qt qt_xxxxxx" where xxxxxx = random 6 digits.

Now I haven't had much experience using GET requests or any back-end at all but I figure this could be a good stepping stone in understanding how to get data from a website and then parse it so I can use it for my gain.

Can anyone offer any insight in how I can achieve pulling the quote text and the author of at least 100 quotes if not more? What kind of problems could I encounter?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific URL you want, this URL doesn't seem to use pages, so I wrote something to scrape the home page, but nothing else so far.

This would be how I would do it.  I use PHP to get around cross origin restrictions and store all the information scraped into ul#quotes.  I use AJAX to fetch the PHP page.

Note: this does take a second to load because you are downloading a webpage in the background.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
    echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
    die();
}

?>

<ul id="quotes">
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.get("?url=https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/deep.html", function (data) {
    $dom = $(data);
    $dom.find(".oncl_q").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).find("img").length)
            $("#quotes").append("<li>" + $(this).html() + "</li>");
    });
})

</script>
```

Comment if you need more help.